# Would asking a question about "why something is" be on topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

What I mean by this is if I asked a question about "why something is a certain way in the gaming industry," would it be on topic?

For example: Why are some games region locked?

Would a question like that be on topic? What tag would be used (gaming-history)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that this would fall under off-topic territory because it's essentially a question about game design.

From the reasons to vote for an off-topic question closure:

> Questions about Game Design and Development are off topic. ***This includes speculative questions about developer intent, with respect to both mechanics and narrative.*** You might want to ask over at GameDev.SE, but be sure to read their FAQ.